# Whether to write an app in xCode or make it a webApp in PHP/mySQL

Tags: mysql, objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data

I have developed an iOS app that uses CoreData/SQLite. It works, but now I have to populate it with data.

I am wondering what the best method would be. As you can see from the title of this post, I am thinking of these two options, but maybe there is another way.

I'm not sure whether I will have multiple people entering data (that would be great), so that is a consideration..

I welcome advice.

Comment: The issue of whether to make a native iOS app or a web app (that presumably is targeted at iPhone users) doesn't have anything to do directly with populating a database. Are you asking about a final client application, or about an app that just a few people would use to enter data for your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a mix of both? you can upload the data to a webserver ( depending on what you want to do with it ). Offer people to have a web app for home and an iphone app for when th ey are on the go. The data they add can be stored locally so they don't need any internet when abroad, which makes the app useable on the ipod touch

Comment: Sounds good, but I'm wondering how interchangeable a web data base will be with an iOS database?

Comment: @David: you don't necessarily need a database on the iPhone at all - instead, you can download needed data from a server.

Comment: @David DelMonte: The databases don't need to be interchangeable — the data just needs to be transmitted in a format both ends can comprehend.

Comment: OK. Thanks all. I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @David you can use sql on both platforms, shouldn't be too much of a problem, also remember to do as much as possible in batches, sqlite3 is not too fast.

Comment: Thanks Antwan, follow-up: can i use mysql on one (ie make a web app), and convert to SQLite/CoreData?

Comment: answering my own comment - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924856/importing-a-mysql-schema-to-xcode-as-a-coredata-data-model - bummer

Answer (score 1):

Native is (almost) always better than web-only. A server is extra overhead; a mix might simplify that a bit. And in most cases, even if your server goes down hopefully users can still use the app with what data they've already downloaded.

Comment: I realized I didn't see this post.. Sorry. I should say that while this wont be a one-time event, it wont be more than a few times (going from the desktop or web version to the iOS app.